# Delete Table row from the 2nd last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table initially with two rows.Every cells of first row titled with word FIRST and every cell of last row  titled with word LAST. **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j1xvtdtt/1/)**

I also have two button one button for adding rows and another for deleting rows.

-On clicking `Add Row` it adds a Row in the 2nd last position upto total 5 rows and become disable.

-But I couldn't figure out how to remove rows one by one from 2nd last upto it's original position on clicking `Delete Row` button.Basically `Delete Row` button will do opposite of **Add row**. Initially Disabled but when there is new row added it will be enabled.

How I can do this ? Thanks in advance.

**JS**

```
// Add and remove row
var counter = 0;
$(".add-xy-scale-row").on("click", function () {

    counter = $('.xy-table tr').length - 1;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";

    newRow.append(cols);
    if (counter == 3) $('.add-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    $(".xy-table .last-row").before(newRow);
    $(".tooltip").hide();
    counter++;

    //Maintain vertical label height
    if ($('.xy-table').height() < 300) {
        $(".scale-label-input-group").addClass("small");
    } else if ($('.xy-table').height() > 300) {
        $(".scale-label-input-group").removeClass("small");
    }

});

$(".dlt-xy-scale-row").on("click", function () {
    $(".xy-table")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubp2dbbt/2/)

You can use jQuery's `.prev()` method to select the previous sibling in the DOM. In this case, you target the last row, `.last-row`, then select the previous sibling and remove it with `.remove()`. I also added in disabling and enabling the Delete button when `counter` is > 0.

**Edit**

Here is the updated JS:

```
// Add and remove row
var counter = $('.xy-table tr').length - 1;
$(".add-xy-scale-row").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";

    newRow.append(cols);
    if (counter == 3) $('.add-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    $(".xy-table .last-row").before(newRow);
    $(".tooltip").hide();

    //Maintain vertical label height
    if ($('.xy-table').height() < 300) {
        $(".scale-label-input-group").addClass("small");
    } else if ($('.xy-table').height() > 300) {
        $(".scale-label-input-group").removeClass("small");
    }

    counter = $('.xy-table tr').length - 1;

    if (counter > 1) {
        $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true);
    }

});

$(".dlt-xy-scale-row").on("click", function () {

    $(".xy-table .last-row").prev().remove();
    counter = $('.xy-table tr').length - 1;

    if (counter > 1) {
        $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true);
    }

    if (counter == 4) {
        $('.add-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    $(".tooltip").hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.add-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "");
    $(".tooltip").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your Example delete the First row. It should not remove what was initially

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was trying to do. Thanks

Comment: @Raihan Great! Please mark my answer as correct if this solves your issue.

Comment: Recommended practice is to show at least the code skeleton in your answer. Otherwise the answer becomes useless in case the original fiddle is unreachable or has been deleted. In addition, the code presentation and the complexity of the complete fiddle might actually hamper understanding the solution's gist.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".xy-table .last-row").prev().remove();
```

Of yourse you need to handle the situation that `$(".xy-table .last-row").prev()` is the first row if you don't want to delete that.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1xvtdtt/2/)

Comment: Well This is the tricky part I guess it should not remove FIRST and LAST titled row

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j1xvtdtt/9/ to see how you can accomplish that. Not tricky at all ;)

Comment: The last line cannot be deleted as `prev` navigates away from it. The first line can be preserved by the jquery `not` filter combined with the `:first-child` selector.

Comment: Your solution still doesn't reactivate the disabled button to add rows.

Comment: You are right. But this was not the OP's problem. i am sure he knows how to solve this ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add and remove rows. It will always remove the row that is equal to the `.deleteRow` item.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwz3wc87/14/) of 100% working iteration with your code.

```
$(document).on('click','#add-row',function(){
        var cells = [
                'CONTENT'
        ],
        cell,
        tbody   = document.getElementById('schedule-items'),
        row     = tbody.insertRow(-1); // -1 = lastRow

    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
       cell = row.insertCell(i);
       cell.innerHTML = cells[i];
    }
});

$(document).on('click','.deleteRow',function(){
    var r = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;

    document.getElementById('schedule-items').deleteRow(r);
});
```

Comment: @Raihan I added a fiddle and you're good to go!! Take a look it is beautiful. Kinda proud of it.

Comment: Fiddle updated again to be version 14 as that is the one where I replace your button text too :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$(".xy-table tr:nth-last-child(2)").remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Use these code updates:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true); 
});

// ...

$(".add-xy-scale-row").on("click", function () {
   // ...
   $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', false);
});

$(".dlt-xy-scale-row").on("click", function () {
    $('.add-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', false);
    $(".xy-table .last-row").prev().not(":first-child").remove();
    if ($(".xy-table .last-row").prev(":first-child").length > 0) {
        $('.dlt-xy-scale-row').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

It will preserve the first row and re-enable the button to add new table rows.

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/3m8Lr1k2/7/) (adopted from the OP's fiddle)

**Edit**

Disabling/enabling the deletion button corrctly handled.

Answer (score 1):

As ImreNagy pointed out, you have to use

```
$(".xy-table .last-row").prev().remove();
```

to remove the second last row.

Then you should add some IFs to ask if the button should be disabled or not like that

```
if(counter > 0){
    $(".dlt-xy-scale-row").removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $(".dlt-xy-scale-row").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j1xvtdtt/1/)